# jtable (jquery) missing dialog format

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-jtable

I'm trying to create jquery jtable according to documentation at [GettingStarted](http://www.jtable.org/GettingStarted).

Everytime a dialog is opened, the entire format/dialog style is missing. I can still see the text and the buttons are links instead, but it looks pretty crappy.

It feels like I'm missing something really trivial but I can't seem to find out what.

I've tried it out [here](http://goo.gl/3bRHC) where you can see the missing style (compared to the several dialogs at [GettingStarted](http://www.jtable.org/GettingStarted)).

I'm using **jquery-1.7.2.min.js** and **jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js** (have also tried CDN version at [jquery-ui.js](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js) with same result).

**EDIT**: There are no logic implemented on purpose here. I'm aware that adding records isn't working, but the style should still show dialogs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look in the source code of [jtable.css](http://leitzler.net/te/jtable/themes/lightcolor/red/jtable.css) it's importing:

```
@import '../jtable_lightcolor_base.css';
```

Does the file exist in your directory structure? If not, then that's probably what's causing the issue.

**Update**

The dialog format is part of jQuery UI and you have not included the jQuery UI CSS

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Yeah, it exists. I'm looking at the page using Chrome with "Developer tools"-feature on and it show's the loaded file without any problems. I.e. http://leitzler.net/te/jtable/themes/lightcolor/jtable_lightcolor_base.css

Comment: Ah ok. Could it be because jQuery UI CSS file is not included? If I do inspect element they look like jQuery UI css styles. I copied your source code and added the jQuery CSS and it's worked.